# In Freemarker, how do I use a custom NumberFormat or DateFormat for 1 line (but not the rest of the report)?

Tags: java, freemarker

I have 2 numbers I want to display in a freemarker file:

- Benchmark `long id`
- Benchmark `long timeSpend`

The id should use the default `NumberFormat` instance, but the timeSpend should use my `MillisecondsSpendNumberFormat` instance, so I get something like this in the output:

- id: `1 234 567`
- timeSpend: `1min 23sec 456ms`

How do I use my `NumberFormat` instance for 1 `long` instance, but not for all of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could give your formatter instance to the Freemarker template (add it to the model that contains the objects being passed to the template) and then explicitly call its format() method to format the number.

Something like

```
timeSpend: ${myCustomFormatter.format(timeSpend)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `${someNumber?string("somePattern")}` to use non-default format for a single occasion. But your real problem will be that FreeMarker always uses `DecimalFormat` for number formatting, and you can only specify the pattern. So you can't use `MillisecondsSpendNumberFormat` at all, unless you invoke it manually. You can either do that by putting a `MillisecondsSpendNumberFormat` instance into the data-model and call it's Java API from the template, or by implementing a `TemplateMethodModelEx` that does the formatting internally, then pull it into some commonly `#include`-d/`#import`-d file with `<#assign formatTimeSpent = "com.example.MyTimeSpentFormatter"?new()>` and then use `${formatTimeSpent(someNumber)}` in the templates.